Own app uploaded via Mobile Device Management, but app cannot be found now
I have uploaded my own app directly to the Playstore via Mobile Device Management, unfortunately something went wrong here (no idea what) and now the app cannot be found and cannot be uploaded again because the package name already exists. Does anyone know the problem and can solve it? If we don't get this solved, the MDM will unfortunately not be usable for our customer.
I already contacted the producer of the MDM but they cannot help me because this is on google site
